# Visual C# forms and command line interface

Tags: c#, command-line

I'm trying to implement a command-line interface inside of a Windows Forms form. I've looked into [PDCurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDCurses), but I'm not sure if that's where I want to be. What should I do?

Comment: You want a console window INSIDE a windows form or just say textboxes set up to display and intput to a cmd shell or simply a separate window?

Comment: yes, that is correct, INSIDE. And I want it formatted, colors, positioning, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic approaches, though I'm not sure which goal you're aiming for:

*If you want to have an actual command window inside your app:*

- Create a text box.  Let them type whatever they want.
- When the user hits ENTER, read the current line and use the System.Diagnostic.Process classes to execute that line and retrieve the resulting text.
- Display the resulting text in your textbox.
- Optional: Prevent the textbox from getting too large by throwing away lines from the top when it gets too big.

*If you want to simply create a custom command-processing window:*

- Find a way to parse the input and provide syntax errors.
- Create an object model that corresponds to the features your app will make available to your console.
- Connect the parser/interpreter to your object model.